# Change invoice date in Magento

Tags: magento, date, invoice

Does anyone know how I can change the order and invoicedate in Magento?
I want to change the order date back in time.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to do this programatically you can modify the information stored in the `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_invoice` tables.

If the invoice date also needs to be updated in the overview you must modify `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_invoice_grid` aswell.

Comment: Thank you Kenny, if I do that.
In the invoice the date is changed but in the overview of all the invoice, the old date still stands there. How can I change that?

Comment: Updated my answer to modify the invoice date in the grid overview.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    /* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice $invoice */
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId);
    $invoice->setCreatedAt(...);
    $invoice->setUpdatedAt(...);
    $invoice->save();
```